# FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS vs. FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS

Tags: android, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

I am having some trouble understanding the difference between these two [`Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) flags and am not 100% certain when each needs to be used and why.

The docs for [`Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS) say:

> Enables Activities to run Activity Transitions either
>   through sending or receiving ActivityOptions bundle created with
>   `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, Pair[])`
>   or `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, View, String)`.

And the docs for [`Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS) say:

> Flag for requesting that window content changes should 
>   be animated using a `TransitionManager`.
>
> The `TransitionManager` is set using 
>   `setTransitionManager(TransitionManager)`.
>   If none is set, a default `TransitionManager` will be used.

The documentation states that the following [`Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) methods require the `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` flag to be enabled, but say nothing about whether or not the `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` needs to be enabled as well (note that according to the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/res/res/values/themes_material.xml#L162-L163), `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` is `true` and `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` is `false` for material-themed applications by default):

- `get{Enter,Exit,Return,Reenter}Transition()`
- `set{Enter,Exit,Return,Reenter}Transition()`
- `getSharedElement{Enter,Exit,Return,Reenter}Transition()`
- `setSharedElement{Enter,Exit,Return,Reenter}Transition()`
- `getTransitionBackgroundFadeDuration()`
- `setTransitionBackgroundFadeDuration()`

In other words, it seems like based on this information `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` is the feature flag that applications will need to enable in order to use Lollipop's new Activity Transition APIs. What confuses me, however, is that [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) from the Android Developers site states that enabling the `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` is required in order to implement custom activity transitions.

So here are my questions:

1. What is the difference between these two flags? What is the difference between an "activity transition" and a "content transition" in this context?
2. Why is `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` enabled and `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` disabled by default? When is enabling the `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` flag actually required?
3. Would it ever make sense to sense to disable `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` and enable `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`? Or does `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` require `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` to be enabled as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Solely based on code digging in the past 10 minutes: 1. Looks like `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` is used when content inside a window changes. For instance, if you call `setContentView(...)` multiple times. Its also used when when you have shared components between activities, say a TextView. 2. `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` could be disabled because it isn't appropriate for every scenario. If you don;t have shared components (or if your ui isn't setup that way), it wouldn't do anything. `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` being enabled kind of makes sense: default transitions and all.

Comment: 3. Take a look at [PhoneWindow#setContentView(int)](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#361). 4. I don't think these flags are needed for Fragment transitions. You do need to set up the transition using `FragmentTransaction` api.

Comment: Yeah, I can see a lot of what you mean by looking at the source code for `PhoneWindow.java`... but the difference between the two still is unclear for me. I still can't really tell whether the two flags are totally independent from each other or not. For example, would it ever make sense to enable `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` but disable `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`, or is this not allowed?

Comment: Either way, it seems to me that the [`Window` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) and the [developer site article](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions), so that is mostly the reason why I am asking for clarification here...

Comment: I'll code this up tomorrow.  That should make things clear. At the moment, the options do look independent.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm glad I have an opportunity to answer these questions as the documentation is less than clear.

Early-on, there was one flag `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` that handled both of the features. We split them when Material applications got unexpected behavior when it was enabled. So some older documentation may still say that you have to enable `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` to get activity transitions when they mean `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`.

> 1. What is the difference between these two flags? What is the
>       difference between an "activity transition" and a "content
>       transition" in this context?

An activity transition in this context means that you call `startActivity` with a bundle created from `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` or, your activity was started with that bundle. Activity Transitions modify your layout (e.g. fading in elements, moving shared elements), so if your activity doesn't like that, you should disable `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`.

Content transitions use a `TransitionManager` when you call `setContentView` (other than the first time). Typically, you'll get a cross-fade, but if your Activity's content has things in common, such as sharing IDs or using `transitionName`, you'll get `ChangeBounds` behavior between those Views. You can change the details of your transitions by customizing the `TransitionManager` associated with your Window either using XML or code.

> 2. Why is `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`
>      enabled and `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` disabled by default? When is
>      enabling the `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` flag actually required?

`FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` uses a TransitionManager when your content changes. By default, this is a cross-fade and that was very bad for some applications. On the other hand, `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` doesn't do anything to most applications by default. You have to opt into starting an activity that way, so it is safe to turn on.

> 3. Would it ever make sense to sense to disable
>      `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` and enable `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`?
>      Or does `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` require
>      `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS` to be enabled as well?

Yes, but it is unlikely. If your application likes `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`, it should work well with `FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`. If you want to explicitly limit people from calling your activity with shared elements or you don't like the standard enter transition effect, you can disable it to prevent the effect when another applications calls into yours.

Comment: Thanks for all of this info! So just to clarify, it sounds like this documentation is incorrect in stating that enabling `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS` is required in order to use custom activity transitions? Just wanted to make sure...

Comment: Yes. FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS is required, but FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS is not.

Comment: @GeorgeMount ~"You have to opt into starting an activity that way".
What do you mean by that?

Comment: In order to launch an activity with an activity transition, you must use ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(...) and pass the bundle into the startActivity call. If someone doesn't call an activity with that, you will get no special animation behavior.

Comment: @GeorgeMount my legacy v21/styles.xml has <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>. Not sure for what it has been added. But now I want to implement activity to activity shared element transition. Can v21/styles.xml have both windowContentTransitions and windowActivityTransitions ? My issue is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074027/illegalargumentexception-in-shared-element-transition