# IllegalArgumentException in Shared Element Transition

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, shared-element-transition

Implemented activity to activity shared element transition. It works fine but receiving crashes on very few devices that are running >=LOLLIPOP.

**Report:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:4654)
       at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5557)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3903)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4146)
       at com.mypackage.Activity1.method1(Activity1.java:414).
```

**tried this:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
     ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity1.this,
                            logoImageView,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(logoImageView));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            } else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.stay);
```

**then this from this sof [IllegalArgumentException in ActivityManagerProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455484/3209739):**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity1.this,
                    logoImageView,
                    getString(R.string.splashLogoSharedTransition));
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
} else {
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashActivity.this,
                    logoImageView,
                    getString(R.string.splashLogoSharedTransition));
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(SplashActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
}
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.stay);
```

Crash happens with the both the codes at:

```
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Ever faced ? Any hints ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class)`?

Comment: @ShahiM yes, copy mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: and does `logoImageView` have the attribute : `android:transitionName="myTransition"`

Comment: Yes, it has. And even the image view in the Activity2 has the same transition. Also v21/styles.xml has <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

Comment: I don't see any more possible issues with the code. I have the exact same code working without issues in one of my projects.

Comment: Just a guess here: `android.os.Parcel.readException` may indicate that the issue is in Activity2, i.e when the bundle is read. Try probing in that direction and hopefully you can figure out the issue.

Comment: I see the bundle is null here: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in the Activity2

Comment: should we mention <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item> even in res/values/styles.xml ? Does this affect anyway to lollipop and above. It should not technically but that's something missing in my code.

Comment: I am using `<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>` in my project in `styles-v21`. please try that instead.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are using `Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`. But Instead, you should be using `Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`.

In your `styles-v21.xml`, add:

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<!-- optional -->
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

From the Docs :

[`Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS):

> Enables Activities to run Activity Transitions either through sending or receiving `ActivityOptions` bundle created with `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, Pair[])` or `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, View, String)`.

[`Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS):

> Flag for requesting that window content changes should be animated using a `TransitionManager`.
>
> The `TransitionManager` is set using `setTransitionManager(TransitionManager)`. If none is set, a default TransitionManager will be used.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28975840/3894781) for more info.

Comment: my v21/styles.xml had <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>. It's a legacy code and I am not sure for what it has been added. Is it okay if I add <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item> also along with content transitions flag in styles?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: cool. Thanks for info. I will add it and see if I will get any more crashes. I think better I should have followed Google doc instead of a blog post which was kinda outdated and was mentioning contentTransition.

Comment: I'll post this fix to play store and see. Crash didn't occur in my phone but from few user's phones. It will work I believe, I'll accept.

Comment: Okay. Cool.  .

Comment: Thanks for the help and answer. Tested in production and so far no crashes.

Comment: I still get crashes in production. Not sure having both contentTransition and activityTransition enabled in v21/styles.xml is causing the issue. Happens only on very few devices.

Comment: I have added try for startActivity(intent, options.toBundle()); and in catch, I started activity without activityOptions so just called startActivity(intent);. Added an event in catch() block to know if crash still happens with this answer. I received 8 of those event so far which means this solution did not help fixing crash. But my app does not crash due to this as I caught Exception. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this post you shouldn't use ActivityOptionsCompat above API 21:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455484/1067763

I don't use it, but I still have this crash:

[Crashes after startActivityForResult in API 27](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47639597/1067763)

I think it's still using the wrong version somehow.

Still, knowing this you might be able to solve your issue.

Comment: I have not used as per my question. Anyway, the crash I am getting is for LOLLIPOP and above when using ActivityOptions as I explained in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the second part is about the very same post. But now I noticed that you are using both ActivityOptions and overridePendingTransitions. I wonder if that could be the source of the problem?

Comment: But I need overridePendingTransitions for my case.